# Do I need to append every generated bundle to composer.json manually?

Tags: symfony

I've started to learn Symfony and I am following some tutorials where there is nothing about this:

When I create a new project with symfony installer and run `composer install` and then `php app/console server:start` I can open that project in my browser.

BUT! When I create a new bundle with command `php app/console generate:bundle` I get this error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "BlogBundle" from namespace "BlogBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /home/user/Symfony/myapp/app/AppKernel.php:19
```

And then I need to go to my composer.json file and append my new generated bundle after AppBundle like this

```
{
    "name": "user/myapp",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "project",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
            "BlogBundle\\": "src/BlogBundle"   // <-- this is the new appended one
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/AppKernel.php",
            "app/AppCache.php"
        ]
    },
    ..........
```

And then when I try to start the server again it works and it shows Hello world in my browser.

So the question is do I have to do this every time (append new generated bundle in composer.json file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is the reason, why you usually have an namespace above that. Some abbreviation of your name or company for example. This way you only add that namespace for the `src` folder and all bundles are "found" automatically.

Example:

```
{
  ...
  "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Acme\\": "src"
         },
  }
  ...
}
```

Now of course your bundles need to use that namespace, eg.:

```
namespace Acme\BlogBundle;

class BlogBundle {
}
```

Comment: This is not quite correct.  A single "psr-4": { "": "src/" }, would handle all cases.  In fact, prior to S3.2 this is exactly what was in composer.json.  Supposedly, specifying the mapping is a bit faster though I'm a bit skeptical.  More info:  https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/issues/1098